# Sherman-Morrison formula and a sum of outer products

Tags: matrices, inverse

A specific form of the general Sherman-Morrison formula reads

$(1+u v^T)^{-1}$ = $1 -  \frac{u v^T}{1+v^T u}$

where $1$ is the identity matrix, $u,v$ are vectors (say with length n) and T denotes the transpose.

Is there a generalization of the formula to sums of outer products, i.e. for $(1+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} u_i v_i^T )^{-1} $ ?

Comment: [Yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity).